# log covariance to arithmetic covariance matrix function?

Tags: r, matrix, covariance

Is there a function that can convert a covariance matrix built using log-returns into a covariance matrix based on simple arithmetic returns?

Motivation: We'd like to use a mean-variance utility function where expected returns and variance is specified in arithmetic terms. However, estimating returns and covariances is often performed with log-returns because of the additivity property of log returns, and we assume asset prices follow a lognormal stochastic process.

Meucci describes a process to generate a arithmetic-returns based covariance matrix  for a generic/arbitrary distribution of lognormal returns on [Appendix page 5](http://www.wilmott.com/pdfs/011119_meucci.pdf).

Comment: don't have time to do this now but it seems easy to implement based on the equations in the linked reference (you could probably even use a `for` loop, but `outer` would be better)

Comment: I think the function would need to take as input an expected returns, and covariance matrix at a horizon. Function would also need to assume  a distribution (normal, cauchy, etc.). I am surprised that a library does not exist for this already -- most covariances are estimated via log returns and this should be a fairly common problem.

Comment: See below. Not so sure about the distribution.  Among other things, if the distribution is really Cauchy then the theoretical second moments don't exist and the sample second moments don't mean very much ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my translation of the formulae:

```
linreturn <- function(mu,Sigma) {
  m <- exp(mu+diag(Sigma)/2)-1
  x1 <- outer(mu,mu,"+")
  x2 <- outer(diag(Sigma),diag(Sigma),"+")/2
  S <- exp(x1+x2)*(exp(Sigma)-1)
  list(mean=m,vcov=S)
}
```

**edit**: fixed `-1` issue based on comments.

Try an example:

```
m1 <- c(1,2)
S1 <- matrix(c(1,0.2,0.2,1),nrow=2)
```

Generate multivariate log-normal returns:

```
set.seed(1001)
r1 <- exp(MASS::mvrnorm(200000,mu=m1,Sigma=S1))-1
colMeans(r1)
## [1]  3.485976 11.214211
var(r1)
##         [,1]     [,2]
## [1,] 34.4021  12.4062
## [2,] 12.4062 263.7382
```

Compare with expected results from formulae:

```
linreturn(m1,S1)

## $mean
## [1]  3.481689 11.182494

## $vcov
##          [,1]      [,2]
## [1,] 34.51261  12.08818
## [2,] 12.08818 255.01563
```

Comment: The "-1" in formula 7 is not a typo. For small values of 'r' where 'r' is the arithmetic return, the log return defined as log(1 + 'r') should be approximately equal to 'r'. If I test the above function with a m1 <- c(.05 , .05) I get wildly high results for $mean, whereas if I keep the "-1" the results of $mean are relatively close to .05 and .05. Indeed, in the limiting case of converting a single security's log return to arithmetic the formula is: exp(1 + logreturn) - 1 = arithmetic return which has a similar functional form to formula 7

Comment: I believe in your simulation experiment you mean to say: r1 <- exp(MASS::mvrnorm(200000,mu=m1,Sigma=S1))-1 (i.e. subtract a negative one). Also, good point on Cauchy. I'll probably use a t-distribution with 5 d.f.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand the context.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me (based on my very limited understanding of the topic) how relaxing the assumption of log-normality to log-t distributions should be implemented -- sorry.

Comment: (Actually t-distribution has unbounded variance). This is a very elegant way of solving the problem, thank you!

Comment: I'll award the bounty near the end of the period so we can get some add'l eyes on the solution. Thanks again!