# Issue converting log return distribution to arithmetic

Tags: r

I am trying to convert my distribution of log returns into arithmetic to solve an asset allocation optimization problem. For some reason the log to arithmetic transformation leads to much larger means and standard deviations then when calculated by using directly the monthly arithmetic returns. I simply can't figure what is wrong with my transformation.

```r
projMuLog <- as.numeric(table.AnnualizedReturns(
        Monthly_Log_Returns, 
           scale = 12, geometric = TRUE)[1,])
projSigmaLog <- 12 * cov(Monthly_Log_Returns)

r1 <- exp(MASS::mvrnorm(200000,mu=projMuLog,
          Sigma=projSigmaLog))-1
colMeans(r1)
var(r1)
```

The output from the transformed log to arithmetic distribution simply do not tally with the results when using the arithmetic return directly.

Using PerformanceAnalytics to calculate monthly log returns from price series then annualized.

Comment: can you please edit your question to indicate that you're using the `PerformanceAnalytics` package?  And can we have a [mcve]?  Finally, are you sure that this is a programming problem and not a math problem?  `exp(mean(log(x))) != mean(x)`, and similarly for `var()` ...

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663690/log-covariance-to-arithmetic-covariance-matrix-function?rq=2 help?

Comment: Yes, I also followed Meucci formula. Indeed, it might be more of a combination of implementation and math issue.